# findbugs report wrong line number and suppress error?

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a java class which use System.GC() to calculate memory usage. However when I run findbugs, it always report wrong line number. 
Question 1: I ran this with intellij findbugs plugin as well as findbugs native GUI. Same result. Am I doing something wrong here?

1. util.MemoryTestBench.lotsOfGC() forces garbage collection; extremely dubious except in benchmarking code
   Class: MemoryTestBench (util)
   Line: 35 - 35  ====> which is Thread.sleep(100) ????????
2. Dead store to handle
   Class: MemoryTestBench (util)
   Line: 23 - 23  ====> which is return usedMemory() - prevUsedMemory ?????

Question 2: how can I suppress error DM_GC ? I tried @SuppressWarnings which didn't work.

test code is as follows:

```
package util;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings;

public class MemoryTestBench {
    @SuppressWarnings (value = "DM_GC",
                       justification = "call GC to measure memory size")
    public static long calculateMemoryUsage(ObjectFactory factory) {
        Object handle = factory.makeObject();
        long prevUsedMemory = usedMemory();
        handle = null;
        lotsOfGC();
        prevUsedMemory = usedMemory();
        handle = factory.makeObject();
        lotsOfGC();
        return usedMemory() - prevUsedMemory;
    }

    private static long usedMemory() {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }


    private static void lotsOfGC() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.gc();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void showMemoryUsage(ObjectFactory factory) {
        long mem = calculateMemoryUsage(factory);
        System.out.println(
                factory.getClass().getSimpleName() + " produced " +
                        factory.makeObject().getClass().getSimpleName() +
                        " which took " + mem + " bytes");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showMemoryUsage(new BigConcurrentHashMapFactory());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put *@SuppressWarnings* before *lotsOfGC* method, but not before *calculateMemoryUsage*